# Pyenv in Production environment

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, updates

I found [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) very useful to do python installation and switch between different versions.

But Can I use `pyenv` in production environment? Are there any risks associated with `pyenv`.
Also I have to upgrade to python 2.7.5 on ubuntu 12.04 on production enviroment.

I read about compiling from the source. Some recommends it, some are against it.
If `pyenv` is not solution what are other options?

Comment: What exactly downsides are you afraid of?

Comment: for pyenv? I am not aware of any issues. I am asking for experts opinion, if it is safe to use it in production. Also I don't want to install from source.

Comment: About safety, I mean. Do you mean `safe=stable` or `safe` in terms of security? We successfully use pyenv for production servers management. As about compiling python, we prefer to compile from source on dedicated (build) servers and then redistribute compiled binaries.